# How to handle this migration error in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, web, laravel-5, migration

I am working in a restaurant system and I am adding a table to the database and have a problem with create_menus_table
I think the problem is in the relations between tables but I can't find it.

I tried to delete all of them and made models again
and checked whether the error in the tables or not 
and delete the database and delete all modules

the error in cmd

> **Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `menus`
>   add constraint `menus_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`)
>   references `users` ())   at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelrestaurantapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
>       660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
>       661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
>       662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
>       663|         catch (Exception $e) {
>
> > 664|             throw new QueryException(
> >         665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> >         666|             );
> >         667|         }
> >         668|    Exception trace:   1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
> >     syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> >     version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")
> >           C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelrestaurantapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452
> >     2   PDO::prepare("alter table `menus` add constraint
> >     `menus_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users`
> >     ()")
> >           C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelrestaurantapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452
> >     Please use the argument -v to see more details.**

the menus table

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMenusTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->string('image');
        // to make relation with the users table as the menu has several users
        // as one to many relationship
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->reference('id')->on('users');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('menus');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::table('jobs', function($table) {

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

try that

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravelrestaurant`.`#sql-3c38_77` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `menus` add constraint `menus_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Answer (score 0):

> just typo error it's references not reference
>   $table->foreign('user_id')->reference('id')->on('users');

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravelrestaurant`.`#sql-3c38_99` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `menus` add constraint `menus_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))